# Why is `mongorestore` not restoring one of my collections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongorestore

I have rails app which requires mongo dump of a test database, which I restore using something like

```
mongorestore -d test_database dump/test_databse
```

when I run this command from the terminal everything works fine

```
$ mongo test_database
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.12
connecting to: test_database
> db.users_user.count()
50
> db.users_posts.count()
100
```

but when I run the same command using Ruby

```
system "mongorestore -d test_database dump/test_databse"
```

one of the collections `users_posts` is not inserted

```
$ mongo test_database
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.12
connecting to: test_database
> db.users_user.count()
50
> db.users_posts.count()
0
```

What's going on here? Is it a permissions issue? I am stumped.

Comment: Logs (server)? Output? Did you try with option `--drop`?

Comment: tried the `--drop` option, still the same